Pandas expand Dataframe to calculate Fractions
Currently im working on a problem where i have to calculate fractions on a dataset.
The Dataframe is roughly in this form



Location
Total Values
Total Values 2




Location 1
100
300


Location 2
200
400



Then i have some fractions i want to calculate:



Ident
Fraction




Frac A
0.25


Frac B
0.75



I would like to create a new dataframe like this



Location
Total Values
Total Values 2




Location 1 A
25
75


Location 1 B
75
225


Location 2 A
50
100


Location 2 B
150
300



Right now im iterating over the rows, creating a new row based on the source row, appending the newly created row to list and then merging the list with the original dataframe
ccalculated = []
for _, row in df_source.iterrows():
   for ident in df_fractions:
      new_row = row.copy()
      scaling_factor = df_fractions[df_fractions.loc[:, "Ident"] == "Frac A"]
      for values in ValueCols: 
         new_row[values] = np.multiply(new_row["Total Values"], scaling_factor)
     calculated.append(new_row)

But this is very slow and i feel like there has to be a better solution

Use merge with cross join and multiple Fraction column by DataFrame.mul:
df = df1.merge(df2[['Fraction']], how='cross')

cols = ['Total Values','Total Values 2']

df[cols] = df[cols].mul(df.pop('Fraction'), axis=0)
print (df)
     Location  Total Values  Total Values 2
0  Location 1          25.0            75.0
1  Location 1          75.0           225.0
2  Location 2          50.0           100.0
3  Location 2         150.0           300.0

